# How to Replace One Array index with another array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Am using Php as my serverside scripting language.In my project I used Json string decoded into array.
My problem is how to overwrite the existing array index based on an array value.

my existing array looks like :

```
$array1 =[
           {
             "Name":"apple",
             "color":"red",
             "property":[
                          {
                            "p1":"value1",
                            "p2":"value2"
                          }
                       ]
           },
           {
             "Name":"Grape",
             "color":"violet",
             "property":[
                          {
                            "p1":"value1",
                            "p2":"value2"
                          }
                     ]
           }
         ];
```

and the updated array content looks:

```
$upadatearray = [
                  {
                     "Name":"apple",
                     "color":"green",
                     "property":[
                                  {
                                    "p1":"newvalue",
                                    "p2":"newvalue2"
                                  }
                               ]
                  }
                ];
```

I want to update the existing $array1 with new $upadatearray , bsed on the "Name" .If it is same then replace.

I want to look like:

```
$finalarray =[
                {
                  "Name":"apple",
                  "color":"green",
                  "property":[
                               {
                                 "p1":"newvalue",
                                 "p2":"newvalue2"
                               }
                             ]
                },
                {
                  "Name":"Grape",
                  "color":"violet",
                  "property":
                             [
                               {
                                 "p1":"value1",
                                 "p2":"value2"
                               }
                             ]
                }
           ];
```

I tried this :

```
for($j=0;$j<count($array1);$j++)
{
     if($array1[$j]['Name'] == $upadatearray[0]['Name'])
     $finalarray = array_replace($array1[$j],$upadatearray[0]);
}
```

But it will not work correctly.Is there any possible solution ?

Comment: It seems like `$array1` and `$upadatearray` are not correct php arrays. You can convert json string to php array like this: `$arr = json_decode($json, true));`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes , I decode the json string into the php array with json_decode() which is mentioned in my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let you have this two arrays:

```
$array1 ='[{"Name":"apple","color":"red","property":[{"p1":"value1","p2":"value2"}]},{"Name":"Grape","color":"violet","property":[{"p1":"value1","p2":"value2"}]}]';

$upadatearray = '[{"Name":"apple", "color":"green", "property":[{"p1":"newvalue","p2":"newvalue2"}]}]';

$array1 = json_decode($array1, true);
$upadatearray = json_decode($upadatearray, true);
```

You can use `array_replace` function. But to make it replace items based on the `Name` column you should first make this column a key of array

```
function make_column_key($arr, $col_name) {
  $keys = array_column($arr, $col_name);
  $result = array_combine($keys, $arr);
  return $result;
}

$array1 = make_column_key($array1, 'Name');
$upadatearray = make_column_key($upadatearray, 'Name');
```

And now simply use `array_replace`

```
$finalarray = array_replace($array1, $upadatearray);
```

If you don't need `Name` be the key of final array, you can get only values:

```
$finalarray = array_values($finalarray);
```

Comment: thanks for your time@Pavel . But it shows $finalarray contains " null" only

Comment: @vinuprasad for me [it shows](http://rextester.com/TPGRO93489) correct `$finalarray`

Answer (score 1):

hi I think this code will help you.

```
//what i did is i created a final array variable which gets the value of  old array.
$finalArray = $array1;

//then i perform a foreach loop for old array
foreach ($array1 as $key => $oldarray) {
    //inside the updated array
    foreach ($upadatearray as $key => $newarray) {
        //if old array name and new array name is same replace content on the final array
        if ($oldarray['Name'] == $newarray['Name']) {
            $finalArray['Name'] = $newarray['Name'];
        }
    }
}
```